# CSS Floating misaligns vertically

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

something that has annoyed me quite a lot lately when trying to float my menu and search to the right is that when specifying a float, the vertical alignment breaks. I want the menu to be perfectly vertical aligned to the "search" text (vertical align baseline), as it is in the first example (with no styling).

I'd rather not group the two in a div and then float it, and I'd rather not position them absolutely or relatively.

[image: illustration]

**DEMO:**
http://jsbin.com/futimadivuka/1/edit

Comment: Grouping and floating the container is the way to go. Whether you'd rather or not.

Comment: Grouping will ruin the width of the searchbox, which is exactly 30% of the page wrapper, a code that it shares with some other elements. The `<div>` can't be 100% width of the wrapper because I need to float something to the left, too, and then my perfect width system will break because it takes 30% of the `<div>` width (not the page wrapper width).

Comment: Why do you need it floated?

Comment: @ZachSaucier All I want is to align the two to the right. Another element in the same wrapper should align to the left. This is only possible with float, as far as I'm aware, and I'd rather don't want to group, partly because of what I said in the previous comment. I'm open to use CSS3, e.g. `display:flex`, but I've experienced a little with it, and can't find a proper solution there either (however, I'm not a flexbox pro, so I might have missed something).

Comment: @itamar Here's a visual explanation (the box have to be the same width as searchbox) http://jsbin.com/futimadivuka/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the `line-height` of `nav` from 1 to `80px` in your css, i.e *same* as that of your search box.

CSS:

```
line-height: 80px;
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcrc9xv7/3/).